# how to remove line connecting discontinued point in matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which has one column shows price, and its index is datetime.

```
2018-09-18T02:29:56.5   524.6
2018-09-18T02:29:57.0   524.6
2018-09-18T02:29:57.5   524.8
2018-09-18T02:29:59.0   525.1
2018-09-18T02:29:59.5   525.1
2018-09-18T02:30:00.0   524.8
2018-09-19T21:00:00.5   527.1
2018-09-19T21:00:01.0   527.1
2018-09-19T21:00:01.5   527.3
2018-09-19T21:00:02.0   527.7
2018-09-19T21:00:02.5   527.5
2018-09-19T21:00:03.0   527.6
2018-09-19T21:00:03.5   527.4
```

im trying to plot the timeplot by `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(df)`.
It gives a plot but with a long straight line connecting the discontinued datapoint (last data point on 2018-09-18T02:30:00.0 and the first data point on 2018-09-19T21:00:00.5). Is there a way to remove the connecting line between the data point gap?

Answer (score 0):

sry... i think how i can do it... just use

```
df.plot(x=df.index.astype(str))
```

basically, convert my index from datetime to string, and use the strings as my x-axis